# Address ProperCase to get 8th instead of 8Th

Tags: crystal-reports, uppercase, lowercase, crystal-reports-xi

I need advanced help with the proper case function in crystal reports. I'm using the following formula for individual first and last name fields which work great.

```
ProperCase ({table.field})
```

My issue is finding a way to fix the "T" in my address example below. The "T" needs to read "t" after the 8.

```
8Th Street Apt
```

See screenshot:

[image: Address Error]

Address formula:

```
ProperCase ({table.address1}) + " " + ProperCase ({table.address2})
```

The format looks silly when sending it this way to employees. Please comment your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
    stringvar array ins := split({table.address1} + " "+ {table.address2}," ");
    stringvar out;
    numbervar z := ubound(ins);
    numbervar y;

    for y := 1 to z  DO
    (
    if asc(left(ins[y],1)) in [97 to 122] then ins[y] := propercase(ins[y]) ;
    );
    out := join(ins," ");
    out
```